# How to share multiple values on telegram share links in php?

Tags: php, telegram

I have a  telegram share button on my website. Everything is fine and working very well when I just put one variable on it like:

https://telegram.me/share/url?url=http://localhost/mywebsite/index.php?userID=$username

But now I need to make a change which user can share one of their post with their name on the link something like:

https://telegram.me/share/url?url=http://localhost/mywebsite/index.php?userID=$username&PostId=$userpost

But, when I click on the button the link I can share, is:

https://telegram.me/share/url?url=http://localhost/mywebsite/index.php?userID=$username

as you can see the second variable is not in the link.
I don't know why but for some reasons telegram doesn't let me to put more than one variable on its link.

I wonder if there any way to solve this issue.

Answer (score 3):

Replace `&` with `%26` and you can share the correct link:

https://telegram.me/share/url?url=http://localhost/mywebsite/index.php?userID=$username%26PostId=$userpost